# OpenGL Unresolved external symbol _gluLookAt@72 and _gluPerspective@32 in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I created an empty Win32 application in visual studio 2012. Afterwards, I setup the OpenGL and GLU libraries (glut32.lib OpenGL32.Lib) through `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`. I have the libraries imported, yet the linker seems to tell me that it can't find some of the GLU methods, as the title sugests, _gluLookAt and _gluPerspctive. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add glu32.lib to your "Additional Dependencies" list.

Comment: The thing is, I put it there

Comment: You only listed glut32.lib and OpenGL32.lib.  Are you sure you added glu32.lib also?

Comment: I can't believe that just happened... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, added and it works. But I hadn't added it earlier but the code was building and running fine, So how was that?